# Padding python pivot tables with 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which has an index of dates ranging from 01-01-2014 to 12-31-2015. I would like the index to range from 01-01-2013 to 12-31-2016 and do not know how without modifying the underlying dataset by inserting a row in my pandas dataframe with those dates in the column I want to use as my index for the pivot table.

Is there a way to accomplish this wihtout modifying the underlying dataset?

Comment: Could you provide the code how you generated the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be general here, since there was no sample code or data provided. Let's say your original dataframe is called `df` and has columns `Date` and `Sales`.

I would try creating a list that has all dates from 01-01-2014 to 12-31-2015. Let's call this list `dates`. I would also create an empty list called `sales` (i.e. `sales = []`). At the end of this workflow, `sales` should include data from `dt['Sales']` AND placeholders for dates that are not within the data frame. In your case, these placeholders will be `0`. In my answer, the names of the columns in the dataframe are capitalized; names of lists start with a lower case.

Next, I would iterate through `dates` and check to see if each date is in `dt['Date']`. Each iteration through the list `dates` will be called `date` (i.e. `date = dates[i]`).

- If `date` is in `dt['Date']`, I would append the `Sales` data for that date into `sales`. You can find the date in the dataframe through this command: `df['Date']==date`.  So, to append the corresponding `Sales` data into the list, I would use this command `sales.append(df[df['Date']==date]['Sales']`.
- If `date` is NOT in `dt['Date']`, I would append a placeholder into `sales` (i.e. `sales.append(0)`.

Once you iterate through all the dates in the list, I would create the final dataframe with `dates` and `sales`. The final dataframe should have both your original data and placeholders for dates that were not in the original data.